# Combine 2 json using a key

Tags: c#

Suppose i have

Json1:

```
[
   {  
      "key":"1",
      "val2":"5",
      "val3":"short",
      "val4":"pant",
      "val5":"blue",
   },
   {  
      "key":"2",
      "val2":"6",
      "val3":"long",
      "val4":"shirt",
      "val5":"red",
   }
]
```

And I have Json2:

```
[
   {  
      "key":"1",
      "qty":"3"
   },
   {  
      "key":"2",
      "qty":"6",
   }
]
```

I would like to have the following results 
Json3:

```
[
   {  
      "key":"1",
      "val2":"5",
      "val3":"short",
      "val4":"pant",
      "val5":"blue",
      "qty":"3"
   },
   {  
      "key":"2",
      "val2":"6",
      "val3":"long",
      "val4":"shirt",
      "val5":"red",
      "qty":"6"
   }
]
```

is there a way to combine using a key in my case I would want to use the "key" as the key to know what qty to place where.

I'm trying to achieve a similar effect of an inner join to combine them that way.

Thanks,

Comment: We should have a gif of "what have you tried?"

Comment: I've been googling around and i see everyone does a merge just combine two together but i haven't seen anybody do something similar to an inner join. I'm not sure how i could accomplish that

Comment: man convert it into array, loop through both the data check for key and if matching add qty in the first json.

Comment: is that the only way? I'm trying to avoid looping through a ton of nodes

Answer (score 0):

```
var json1 = '[' + 
'{ "key":"1" , "val2":"5", "val3":"short", "val4":"pant","val5":"blue" }, ' +
'{  "key":"2", "val2":"6", "val4":"shirt", "val5":"red" } ]';

var json2 = '[' + 
'{ "key":"1", "qty":"3"}, ' +
'{ "key":"2", "qty":"6" } ]';

var obj1 = JSON.parse(json1);
var obj2 = JSON.parse(json2);

for(var i in obj1) {
if(obj1[i].key === obj2[i].key) {
    obj1[i].qty = obj2[i].qty;
}
}
console.log(obj1);
```

Comment: This answer is using javascript. however, the OP is asking for c# solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using Json.net's [merge method](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/08/04/json-net-6-0-release-4-json-merge-dependency-injection):

```
var json1 = JArray.Parse(@"[
                   {  
                      ""key"":""1"",
                      ""val2"":""5"",
                      ""val3"":""short"",
                      ""val4"":""pant"",
                      ""val5"":""blue"",
                   },
                   {  
                      ""key"":""2"",
                      ""val2"":""6"",
                      ""val3"":""long"",
                      ""val4"":""shirt"",
                      ""val5"":""red"",
                   }
              ]");

var json2 = JArray.Parse(@"[
                   {  
                      ""key"":""1"",
                      ""qty"":""3""
                   },
                   {  
                      ""key"":""2"",
                      ""qty"":""6"",
                   }
                ]");

json1.Merge(json2, new JsonMergeSettings
{
    MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Merge
});
```

Comment: this just merges them...but it doesn't do it based on a key